# I am getting error when i am clicking on the buy now button (paypal). How to solve this?

Tags: paypal, squarespace

Please help me to resolve this paypal's issue. I have implemented paypal gateway method in squarespace. But when i am clicking on the buy now button it shows me this message on my screen. 
"You've been inactive for a while, so we logged you out to help protect your account. Please return to the merchant and restart the payment process."

Comment: Can you share some code?